# How to make a linear progress indicator with swing effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, progress-bar, flutter-animation

I want to make a progress bar that looks like this. If you look closely, the length of the indicator varies when it swings.

[image: Text]

I tried to reuse the linear progress bar that flutter provides.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: controller.value,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And it looks like this.

[image: Text]

Comment: Can you provide full widget?

Comment: sure, updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow  this snippet. Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=aba641cd20ff1632d67c5890857c8493)

`````dart
///  create ---- ProgressIndicator
///
/// ````
/// child: SizedBox(
///    height: 12,
///    child: CustomLinearProgressIndicator(
///      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
///      color: Colors.blue,
///      maxProgressWidth: 100,
///    ),
///  ),
/// ````
class CustomLinearProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomLinearProgressIndicator({
    Key? key,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
    this.maxProgressWidth = 100,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// max width in center progress
  final double maxProgressWidth;

  final Color color;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  @override
  State<CustomLinearProgressIndicator> createState() =>
      _CustomLinearProgressIndicatorState();
}

class _CustomLinearProgressIndicatorState
    extends State<CustomLinearProgressIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller =
      AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1))
        ..addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
        })
        ..repeat(reverse: true);

  late Animation animation =
      Tween<double>(begin: -1, end: 1).animate(controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColoredBox(
      color: widget.backgroundColor,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(animation.value, 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            // play with BoxDecoration if you feel it is needed
            color: widget.color,
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          ),
          // you can use animatedContainer, seems not needed
          width: widget.maxProgressWidth -
              widget.maxProgressWidth * (animation.value as double).abs(),
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`````